# Exception encountered during context initialization whilst starting hazelcast management console

Tags: hazelcast

Please could anyone help me, this comes only when management console, hazelcast server fine.

021-09-01 16:05:21,965 [ WARN] [main] [o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext]: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/MapManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientNearCacheStatsManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/ClientNearCacheStatsManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/metrics/MetricsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsStorage' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/config/MetricsStorageConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.metrics.MetricsStorage]: Factory method 'metricsStorage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2021-09-01 16:05:21,971 [ERROR] [main] [o.s.w.c.ContextLoader]: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mapManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/MapManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'clientNearCacheStatsManager' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/ClientNearCacheStatsManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06/hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar!/com/hazelcast/webmonitor/service/metrics/MetricsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metricsStorage' defined in class path resource [com/hazelcast/webmonitor/config/MetricsStorageConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.webmonitor.metrics.MetricsStorage]: Factory method 'metricsStorage' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:1068) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:572) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.contextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:997) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:746) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:911) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:117) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.Launcher.startServer(Launcher.java:160) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.Launcher.start(Launcher.java:129) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]
at com.hazelcast.webmonitor.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:107) [hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06.jar:?]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you fix this issue?

Comment: we have moved this to a cluster, no longer use management console on my dev machine. Original issue when hazelacast management started on windows powershell using this  "PS C:\hazelcast-management-center-4.2021.06\bin> ./start.sh" was throwing javabean exception i copied initially.   Its fine know because iam using admin rights on powershell to start this.